# Jumping Problems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2D platformer on Unity (I know very little about Unity) and I am trying to make my jump function properly. I have 2 problems, that being that I can't prevent my character from jumping midair, and that my character gets stuck on any walls that I move up against.

The code I have functions properly, but I don't know how to solve these problems.

```
public class movementSide : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpPower;
    private Rigidbody2D body;

    private void Awake()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, body.velocity.y);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, jumpPower);
        }
    }   
}
```

I've spent a while looking through several tutorials trying to find any even slightly simple explanations on how to solve these problems and I cannot.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if you are touching the ground? (Should be needed for landing). If so, then use a conditional (if).

As for the walls: used different sprites for walls and floor (even if they look the same).

What I have said is not Unity specific.